# Android NN API CpuExecutor: Invalid type or dimensions for model output

Tags: android, neural-network, java-native-interface, nnapi

I'm trying to implement a simple two-layer network in Android NN API, but during compilation I get an error:

> E/CpuExecutor: Invalid type or dimensions for model output
>       SOFTMAX failed.
>
> E/CpuExecutor: Invalid type or dimensions for model output
>       SOFTMAX failed.

maybe who knows what this error is connected with?
P/S/ If anyone has a working example of implementation in NN API in repo ? would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the size of the output tensor in the previous layer did not match. If anyone has an example of a built model for classifying an image in NNAPI I will be grateful.